# How to add Prerequisites in installshield 2010?

Tags: .net, installation

How to additional Prerequisites in installshield 2010?

Answer (score 1):

in tools >>prerequisite editor add a prerequisite with default name MyPrerequisite1 then you can rename this name go to path C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2010\SetupPrerequisites
find the file MyPrerequisite1.prq and change name then run install shield